# Download a file to gather data but not show it in the explorer C#

Tags: c#, download, webclient

I'm downloading two files, a txt to get links to download packages and a binary file to perform a hash check, after i do my job with these files, delete them, but before i do, they are shown in the explorer alongside the exe before they are gone, so they appear and disappear, and it looks a bit bad from a client's point of view. Is there any way to download them to get their data without showing it in the explorer?

I'm using System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile for both cases, since they are small, and then i perform a TextReader on the txt and a File.ReadAllBytes on the second one.

Comment: If the files are small, why don't you simply load the data to memory?

Comment: Just download to memory stream or use DownloadString since you then extract text from them anyway.

Comment: Yes! the DownloadString was what i was looking for, thank you! now i have to do the same with the binaryFile, i will try with this DownloadData method i saw too in the WebClient, maybe that's what i was looking for.